# Using qualify inside window function in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, window-functions

I have a dataset where I have tasks, each task corresponds to an user and have an unique id, an amount, and a creation date. Also in each task the amount could be updated and the event will be a new row in the dataset with a last update date corresponding data. So in the dataset I have task events. I want for each task, to sum the total amount of all the tasks of an user  but adding the amount of the task  with the max date before the task pivot. I know I can use window functions to sum using each task id as pivot and partitioning by user.

```
    select task_id, SUM( task_amt) over(partition by user  order by DATE_DIFF(TIMESTAMP(date), TIMESTAMP('2007-12-31 12:00:00+00'), SECOND) 
 range between 7776000 preceding and 1 preceding)) as task_amt from table
```

In that case I am adding all the events corresponding to a task which is wrong. I want to add only the last event before de creation date of the task pivot.
[image]

If we use the table above as an example for the payment with id C i want the result to be 25. Because I want to sum the last event before de date of C of A and B,  which are version 1 of A and version 0 of B. We can see the two rows to sum in the following table:
[image]

I am adding the last version of each payment with the last_update_date before the creation date of C.

So the final result should be like this;
[image]

Is there anyway I can add a qualify to the window function to achieve that? Or should I try with another tool like spark?

Here is the code to create the table

```
    CREATE TABLE table (
  id INT64,
  user STRING,
  amt FLOAT64,
  date DATE,
  last_update_Date TIMESTAMP,
  version INT64
);

INSERT INTO table (id, user, amt, date, last_update_Date, version)
VALUES
  (1, 'a', 10.0, '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01 12:00:00', 0),
  (1, 'a', 20.0, '2020-01-01', '2020-02-01 12:00:00', 1),
  (1, 'a', 30.0, '2020-01-01', '2020-03-01 12:00:00', 2),
  (2, 'a', 5.0, '2020-02-10', '2020-02-10 12:00:00', 0),
  (2, 'a', 10.0, '2020-02-10', '2020-03-10 12:00:00', 1);

INSERT INTO table (id, user, amt, date, last_update_Date, version)
VALUES
  (3, 'a', 100.0, '2020-02-11', '2020-02-11 12:00:00', 0),
  (3, 'a', 200.0, '2020-02-11', '2020-02-15 12:00:00', 1);
```

Comment: why is `mysql` in the tags? please only use tags that are specifically related to the question, even the tag `sql`, if you read the description of it,doesn't need to be used here it seems

Comment: It would help - a lot - to provide "the expected result" as a table instead of tryig to describe that result by words.

Comment: oh dear - you have used an image to display the data - what a pity. If you used just plain text I could have tested my proposed solution - but we don't have time to transcribe your data (and make mistakes in that data  along the way)

Comment: hey. I update the question with all the comments I think that now is more clear. Sorry for the issues.

Comment: Is `id` column contains some kind of order or just a string key? I am not sure what to choose for `payment B`. Is it just `payment A` or all other payments based on `last_update_date`?

Comment: id column is just a string key, you can use date for get order. For payment B you want to add the last update before B creation date (2020-02-10) of all the other payments (in this case just payment A), in this case just version 1 of payment A because it was updated on 2020-02-01

Comment: in the table def & in the sample data ID is an integer, all values given in the inserts are 1. all user values are "a" so the sample data isn't as per the image and it is impossible to give a result containing "a","b","c" in an ID column. If the sample data is really as per the table def & inserts then your expected result is just wrong.

Comment: Just corrected the image table to be coherent with the code, it  was a typo

Comment: I would recommend not using reserved keywords such as `date` as column names.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be using `QUALIFY` with `CROSS JOIN` and `Sub Queries`.

p.s. You might want to change the detail conditions on `CROSS JOIN`ing when comparing `timestamps` with `DATE`.

#### Query (w/ DML)

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE dataset (
    id INT64, user STRING, amt FLOAT64, create_date DATE, last_update_Date TIMESTAMP, version INT64
);

INSERT INTO dataset (id, user, amt, create_date, last_update_date, version)
VALUES
    (1, 'a', 10.0, '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01 12:00:00', 0),
    (1, 'a', 20.0, '2020-01-01', '2020-02-01 12:00:00', 1),
    (1, 'a', 30.0, '2020-01-01', '2020-03-01 12:00:00', 2),
    (2, 'a', 5.0, '2020-02-10', '2020-02-10 12:00:00', 0),
    (2, 'a', 10.0, '2020-02-10', '2020-03-10 12:00:00', 1),
    (3, 'a', 100.0, '2020-02-11', '2020-02-11 12:00:00', 0),
    (3, 'a', 200.0, '2020-02-11', '2020-02-15 12:00:00', 1)
;

WITH
payment_id_with_last_update_date AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM dataset
    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY last_update_date DESC) = 1
),
cross_joined_table AS (
    SELECT
        filterd_table.id as id,
        original_table.id as joined_id,
        original_table.amt,
        original_table.last_update_date,
    FROM payment_id_with_last_update_date AS filterd_table
    CROSS JOIN dataset as original_table
    WHERE DATE(original_table.last_update_date) <= filterd_table.create_date
        AND original_table.id != filterd_table.id
    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY filterd_table.id, original_table.id
        ORDER BY original_table.last_update_date DESC
    ) = 1
)
SELECT
    payment_id_with_last_update_date.id,
    IFNULL(SUM(cross_joined_table.amt), 0) AS amt,
FROM payment_id_with_last_update_date
LEFT OUTER JOIN cross_joined_table USING (id)  -- to show records with zoro
GROUP BY payment_id_with_last_update_date.id
ORDER BY payment_id_with_last_update_date.id DESC
;
```

#### Results

[image]

Comment: wow! that is whtat I was looking for! thanks